# Is there a way to get in touch with Barry Hughart?

Tags: authors, translation

... author of Bridge of Birds?

A friend of mine would like to enquiry about the possibility to translate the three novels in a foreign language, and what the terms would be for this.

I have tried to find a way to contact the author directly, but the only resources I have found online are all obsolete.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the Tucson telephone directory?

Comment: You might also try contacting Mike Berro as seen at http://www.barryhughart.org/

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, Barry Hughart died in August 2019.

Try his publishers. They should be able to put you in touch with his estate or his agent. If they don't give you the contact info, they should at least forward your message.

The most recent edition of *The Chronicles of Master Li and Number Ten Ox* (which collects all three novels) is from [Subterranean Press](https://subterraneanpress.com), info@subterraneanpress.com.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing recent information into your answer.

Comment: @SQB: Thank you!